# Why is a menu item disabled when using SWTBot?

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, user-interface, gui-testing, swtbot

I've written up [a GUI test](https://github.com/vazexqi/CodingSpectator/blob/test-using-swtbot/edu.illinois.eclipsewatcher.ui.tests/src/edu/illinois/eclipsewatcher/tests/ExtractMethodTest.java) using [SWTBot](http://www.eclipse.org/swtbot/) to test the Extract Method refactoring. I use `editor.selectRange()` to select a statement to extract into a method. But, when I run the unit test, the Extract Method refactoring menu item is disabled. Thus, SWTBot fails to invoke the refactoring.

When we change `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.ExtractMethodAction` so that the "Extract Method..." menu item is always enabled, our SWTBot passes. But, SWTBot should let us select the menu item without hacking the `org.eclipse.jdt.ui` plugin.

The whole project containing the above unit test is [available at github](https://github.com/vazexqi/CodingSpectator/tree/test-using-swtbot/edu.illinois.eclipsewatcher.ui.tests). I've also reported the problem on [the Eclipse forum for SWTBot](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=rview&goto=558874&th=175411) and [SWTBot bug tracking system](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=333512). But, we haven't received a solution from the forum.

Comment: You mean editor.setSelection()? Because getSelection() won't select anything...

Comment: @Zoltán Ujhelyi, I meant selectRange(). I fixed the problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you must flush any pending events to enable the menu. Add this loop before you try to click on the menu:

```
while(Display.getDefault().readAndDispatch());
```

[EDIT] I think the problem is that the menu is enabled through an extension point or a condition. Check all the plugin.xml files for the menu or the underlying action and on which condition it becomes enabled.

To trigger the condition, you may have to notify the workbench about the new selection. Check http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-WorkbenchSelections/article.html and http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-action-contribution/index.html

Comment: @Aaron Digulla Thanks for the suggestion. We tried it. But, it didn't work for us because the extract method refactoring menu doesn't become enabled.

Comment: Ah ... I think I know where this is coming from. See my edits.

Comment: The following is how the `Extract Method Refactoring` is set up in the `org.eclipse.ui.actionSets` extension point of `org.eclipse.jdt.ui/plugin.xml`.

`<action definitionId="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.extract.method"
label="%Refactoring.extractMethodAction.label"
retarget="true"
menubarPath="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.refactoring.menu/codingGroup"
id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.ExtractMethod">
</action>`

Comment: The extension does not seem to specify the condition under which the menu becomes enabled. Is that the `plugin.xml` you were referring to?

Comment: Yes. I think your problem is that you need Eclipse to run the condition. Not sure how that works. Did you have a look into the test cases for other plugins, especially those in the JDT that test refactoring?

Comment: Do you know if the `conditions` are supported in the version of `plugin.xml` that JDT uses? I believe JDT is using an old format of `plugin.xml` that doesn't support `conditions`.

Comment: Sorry, no idea. Consider asking in the JDT forum: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=13